# Netcat FTP active mode file transfer not working

Tags: ftp, connection, port, file-transfer, netcat

Im trying to download a file from a FTP server using active mode.However,it looks like my connection just"expire" or something each time.First,I open a port on my computer using netcat,ex:

```
nc -vv -l -p 62077
```

this will listen on port 62077 on my computer.Then,I open another netcat windows,log in to the FTP link using port 21,and once im in the directory where the file I want is in,I do

```
PORT (my IP separated by , ),(242,125(wich equals to port 62077)\r\n
```

However,after I enter this command,nothing happen for about 10-15 seconds,and the netcat just quit without saying anything.Nothing happen either on the netcat window that is listening on port 62077.It does that everytime,I dont know what I am doing wrong.I did the same thing with Filezilla(in active mode) and examinated the commands with wireshark,I do the exact same command as Filezilla,however filezilla will be able to retrieve the file while netcat wont.I want to retrieve it with netcat and I dont know what im doing wrong.I am using Windows 10.

thank you!

Comment: Are you sure the remote server can connect to your port 62077? The timeout sounds suspiciously like a TCP timeout.

Comment: Show us the FileZilla log file. And server-side log file, if you have an access to it.

Answer (score 0):

After you have established your listening `nc` socket, *and* after you have sent the `USER`, `PASS`, and `PORT` commands, you *then* need to trigger the file transfer to that listening socket using *e.g.*:

```
RETR /path/to/file/to/download
```

on the control connection.  (Unless you actually *are* already doing this, but didn't mention it in the post?)

Also, just to note: you mention using something like this:

```
PORT 1,2,3,4,(242,125)\r\n
```

Right?  Those parentheses *might* also be an issue.  Instead, you might try:

```
PORT 1,2,3,4,242,125\r\n
```

without any parentheses.

Now, depending on the IP address you sent (hopefully not a [private network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) address), the data transfer may still not happen, due to firewalls/routers/NAT on the client side of things.  Given that your Filezilla download of the same file works, I suspect that those firewall/router/NAT issues may not apply.

Hope this helps!